# How to make nested divs?

Tags: html, css

HTML novice here. Go easy on me.

My code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Simple encrypt/decrypt</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        body 
        {
            background-color: #A9F5F2;
            width: 900px;
        }
        .outerdiv
        {
            margin: 5px;
            border: 2px solid #FF8000;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            font-family: Arial;
        }
        #col1
        {
            width: 550px;
            height: 800px;
        }
        #col2
        {
            width: 200px;
            height: 800px;
        }
        #title1div
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
        #insctdiv
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
        #iptdiv
        {
            height: 400px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #buttonsdiv
        {
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #inputText
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            resize: none;
        }

    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        function encrypt()
        {
            var text = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
            newstring = "";
            /* Make newstring a string of the bit representations of 
               the ASCII values of its thisCharacters in order.
            */
            for (var i = 0, j = text.length; i < j; i++) 
            { 
                bits = text.charCodeAt(i).toString(2);
                newstring += new Array(8-bits.length+1).join('0') + bits;
            }
            /* Compress newstring by taking each substring of 3, 4, ..., 9 
               consecutive 1's or 0's and it by the number of such consecutive
               thisCharacters followed by the thisCharacter. 
               EXAMPLES:
                    "10101000010111" --> "10101401031"
                    "001100011111111111111" --> "0011319151"
            */
            newstring = newstring.replace(/([01])\1{2,8}/g, function($0, $1) { return ($0.length + $1);});      
            document.getElementById("inputText").value = newstring;
        }

        function decrypt()
        {
            var text = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
            text.replace(/([2-9])([01])/g,
            function (all, replacementCount, bit) {
                return Array(+replacementCount + 1).join(bit);
            }).split(/(.{8})/g).reduce(function (str, byte) {
                return str + String.fromCharCode(parseInt(byte, 2));
            }, "");
            document.getElementById("inputText").value = text;
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="col1">
        <div class="outerdiv" id="title1div">
            <h1>Reversible text encryption algorithm</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="outerdiv" id="insctdiv">
            <p>Type in or paste text below, then click <b>Encrypt</b> or <b>Decrypt</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="outerdiv" id="iptdiv">
            <textarea id="inputText" scrolling="yes"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="outerdiv" id="buttonsdiv">
            <button onclick="encrypt()"><b>Encrypt</b></button>
            <button onclick="decrypt()"><b>Decrypt</b></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outerdiv" id="col2">
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

As you can see in the body, I have two divs, col1 and col2, which I was hoping would end up as two columns. Since the width of col1 is 550 pixels and the width of col2 is 200px and the width of the body is 900 pixels, shouldn't this mean that col1 and col2 would be next to each other? I thought the only reason col2 would be under col1 would be if it was pushed down there because their combined widths exceeded the width of the page. But maybe my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ths below should show how nested divs works and how to float them next to each other

css

```
.wrapper{
position:relative;
margin:0px auto 0px auto;
padding:0px;
width:90%;
height:500px;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);}

.left,.right{
position:relative;
float:left;
display:block;
margin:5%;
padding:0px;
width:40%;
height:40%;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);}
```

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
    left <br />
        <div class="left">
            left
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            right
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        right
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use float: left; on both col1 and col2 to have them sit next to each other. It is only needed on col1, but technically it won't hurt anything to put it on both.

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` are block (display:block) and will always be below each other unless you use float: left or float: right or display:inline-block;.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
#col1, #col2{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try applying `float:left` to `col1`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the float css property

```
float: [left | right];
```

in this instance set "float: left;" on col1 like so

```
#col1 {
     float: left;
}
```

side note:
i would recommend setting these as classes rather than IDs though as so:

```
.col1 {
     float: left;
}
```

also, edit col1 to:

```
<div class="col1">...
```